# How to visualise Jest tests coverage report in WebStorm

Tags: jestjs, webstorm, test-coverage

I was trying to visualize unit test code coverage report in WebStorm. I run Jest tests and generate coverage reports, (as you can see on the screenshot from WebStorm IDE bellow) but somehow only for one of the libs this reports is visualised and I can't understand why we can see this only for 'core' and not for 'components' or 'themes' libs.

**Question is how to enable visualization of jest coverage report inside WebStorm IDE ?**

PS I am using NX Monorepo setup if this maybe the issue.

[image]

PS Here some progress on the issue apperantly in order to see the coverage report inside the Webstorm it has to be present in "Show Coverage Data" window (check the screenshot bellow). Now the problem is that Webstorm allows for you to manually add a directory with coverage report but after you do this nothing happens. ONLY if you run your test via the "Run with Coverage" button in the IDE the generated report is recognized by Webstorm and automatically added to "Show Coverage Data" window, this looks like a bug in Webstorm IDE can someone confirm this behaviour.

[image]

Comment: must be specific to the project setup, hard to tell without the project:(

Comment: @lena tnx I will try to build a small example project. But in general do you know how this visualization of coverage is triggered in the project window of Webstorm ? I kind of kind not find reference for this feature ?

Comment: normally it's displayed in the corresponding `lcov` produced by the coverage tool can be located and parsed

Comment: @lena So I have a new development on the issue. So I found how to make Webstorm visualize the coverage report inside IDE. Apperantly only if you run the tests via the IDE "Run with coverage" button they are visualized. After you run the test via this button they will appear inside the "Show Coverage Data" window. This looks like a clear Webstorm bug because if you generate the coverage report on you own and try to add it to "Show Coverage Data" window nothing happens :(. Any advice ?

Comment: not a bug, this is the expected behavior: to view the coverage in IDE, you need using "run with coverage" action. Related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10303

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your prompt. I already know the reason.
You told me about the "Run with Coverage" feature, and I used it to find a solution to the problem.
It actually calls --verbose as an argument.

So, you just type the command: jest --verbose --coverage into the terminal and you get a detailed report. Then you can use "Show Coverage Data" to open the coverage folder under the project folder, open lcov.info, and browse the test coverage for the entire project.